# Application Development in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, cross-platform, hybrid-mobile-app, multi-device-hybrid-apps

I would like to develop an application both in iOS and android.
I just tried **ionic framework and xamarin (forms)** for the development. I found that ionic framework is not suitable for my application, but I am very impressed with Xamarin. Xamarin have only a **limited support**.
How can I take a Xamarin Enterprise license? Is the Enterprise license help me to get official development support?

Comment: Check out [this guide](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/windows/visual-studio/) for some understanding

Comment: can you specified official development support? because as far i know the enterprise license only for the IDE and if you need technical support assistant or you want to access the cloud test, you need to subscribe to those specific services. But the best way to confirm this is by contacting xamarin

Comment: thanks, Is there any official mail support if I feels any difficulty during development?

Comment: Ganesh Cauda : I already send some mails to "hello@xamarin.com", but only got a system generated response that says "one of their member will contact soon", then no response from their side.

Answer (score 0):

If you have VS Professional or Enterprise you get Support from Microsoft / Xamarin, if you use the free Community Edition then you get community support, see https://www.xamarin.com/compare-visual-studio

There’s also a network of Xamarin Partners and a Consultants who can give you bespoke support tiered to exactly what you need. Email them to explain the level of support you need and they will let you know he best route